# Add two input fields in add_settings_field

Tags: settings-api

I want to add a third column consisting of an input textfield using the Settings API. Is this possible?

```
function print_custom_field()
{
    $value = get_option( 'my_first_field', '' );
   $value_second = get_option( 'my_second_field', '' );
    echo '<input type="text" id="my_first_field" name="my_first_field" value="' . $value . '" />';
echo '<input type="text" id="my_second_field" name="my_second_field" value="' . $value_second . '" />';
}

add_filter('admin_init', 'register_fields');
```

EDIT: I tried this code and Wordpress doesn't save the values of the second input field. Only the value of the first input field gets saved. How can I show another text input in the same row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was `register_setting` for the second input.

Comment: Can you please provide example? What if you are using array format ie. <input name="your_option[second_field]">?

Answer (score 0):

[From the settings  API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field),

```
add_settings_field(
    'my_first_field-id',
    'This is the setting title',
    'myprefix_setting_callback_function',
    'general',
    'myprefix_settings-section-name',
    array( 'label_for' => 'my_first_field-id' )
);
myprefix_setting_callback_function(){

  echo '<input type="text" name="my_first_field" value="'.get_option('my_first_field').'" />';
}
```

Comment: Sorry that's not what I asked. I want to add another input field in the same row.